# Adding protos but keeping object structure, javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype

Lets say I get this from an API:

```
var _persons = [
  {
    name: 'John'
  },
  {
    name: 'Sarah'
  }
];
```

Now I want to add a greeting function. I want to save memoryspace so I create a `Person 'class'` and add the function as a proto.

```
function Person(person){
  this.person = person;
}

Person.prototype.greeting = function(){
  return 'hello ' + this.person.name
};
```

I instantiate each person:

```
var persons = [];
function createPersons(people){
  for(var i = 0;i<people.length;i++){
    var person = new Person(people[i]);
    persons.push(person);
  }
};

createPersons(_persons);
```

Problem is this:

```
console.log(persons[0].name) //undefined
console.log(persons[0].person.name) //'John'
```

Is there anyway I can get the first console.log to work?

https://jsbin.com/zoqeyenopi/edit?js,console

Comment: you're using `people` as the passed parameter name but iterating over `_persons`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid the `.person` appearing in the object you need to copy each property of the source plain object directly into the `Person` object:

```
function Person(p) {
    this.name = p.name;
    ...
}
```

[or use a loop if there's a large number of keys]

You've then got a mismatch between the named parameter and the variable you're iterating over in the `createPersons` function.   Additionally it would make more sense to have that function `return` the list, not set an externally scoped variable:

```
function createPersons(people) {
    return people.map(function(p) {
        return new Person(p);
    });
}

var persons = createPersons(_persons);
```

NB: the above uses `Array.prototype.map` which is the canonical function for generating a new array from a source array via a callback.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over all the keys in your object argument and assign them to `this`

```
function Person(person){
    for (var key in person) {
      this[key] = person[key];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var persons = [];
function createPersons(people){
  for(var i = 0;i<people.length;i++){
    var person = new Person(people[i]);
    persons.push(person);
  }
};

createPersons(_persons);
```

Should be using people as a variable

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a `Person` object that is given a variable `person`. You need to change the value you're getting by replacing

```
var person = new Person(people[i]);
```

with

```
var person = new Person(people[i]).person;
```

```js
var _persons = [
  {
    name: 'John'
  },
  {
    name: 'Sarah'
  }
];

function Person(person){
  this.person = person;
}

Person.prototype.greeting = function(){
  return 'hello ' + this.person.name;
};

var persons = [];
function createPersons(people){
  for(var i = 0;i<people.length;i++){
    var person = new Person(people[i]).person;
    persons.push(person);
  }
};

createPersons(_persons);

console.log(persons[0].name); // logs 'John'
document.write('John');
```